# How to VNC to Ubuntu 14.04+ (16.04, 18.04) from Windows without turning off require-encryption in vino?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vnc

A well known problem with Ubuntu's default VNC Server (vino) since at least 14.04 is that by default it [sets require-encryption to be true](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/07/remote-access-ubuntu-16-04/).

Sometimes, there are situations where we cannot change this and it is super annoying to jump through hoops just to get a temporary VNC connection up.

**Is there a VNC viewer that can be used to connect to a require-encryption vino server?**

Most VNC viewers that are common (RealVNC, TightVNC, TigerVNC), don't seem to support this.

Note that there is a long-outstanding bug w/ vino to fix this (but it hasn't yet happened yet): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/1281250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying many VNC viewers with different options to see if I could solve my own question.

Anyhow, TurboVNC will do the trick, but not the native Windows client. Use the **TurboVNC Java Viewer**. At least it works in the "VNC Password" mode. I did not try a different setting on the server. This also has the advantage that means it'll be more cross-platform.

[Desktop Sharing Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNSWR.jpg)

See: https://sourceforge.net/p/turbovnc/mailman/message/35633296/ (for the hint)

I've also tried SSVNC and it does not work. The Stunnel it sets up, dies after you entire your password.